# PostgreSQL 9.1: set comment on table with returning value from a function

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

If I use this piece of code to write the comment on a TABLE everything works fine:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE schemaname.tablename IS 'Some Comment';
```

But if I want to use a function's return value as the value of the comment I have an error, like here:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE schemaname.tablename IS substring('Thomas' from 2 for 3);

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "substring"
```

Any idea on how to fix this? (I would not like to edit the 'pg_catalog.pg_description' system table)

Thank you.
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for that:

```
do
$body$
declare
  comment_string text;
begin
  comment_string := substr('thomas', 2, 3);
  execute 'comment on table public.foo is '||quote_literal(comment_string);
  commit;
end;
$body$
```